# Android - Best way to do asynchronous tasks

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, background-process

I have a very intensive task, where I parse around 100 json files stored in assets and create a tree structure from that..
Then i update the UI based on resulted tree.l

Currently, I am using AsyncTask to do this job.

But, I am looking for better, efficient and clean way to do this. Any libraries or any other in-built functionality which i should use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with an `IntentService` here. It already provides a background thread and it will stop itself once it's done. If you need to update the UI after that, you can use a `Handler` or a `BroadcastReceiver`.

**EDIT**

You can still use an `AsyncTask` but still, start it from a `Service`. `AsyncTask` is just a wrapper around java thread, it's not an Android component. You have to start it from some context, in this case it's either `Activity` or `Service`.

If you start it from `Activity` then your long-running operation will depend on the UI which in most  cases will cause a memory leak. `Service` is a background component which runs independently from the UI. Also, `Service` will increase your app's process priority so that it less likely to be killed by Android when the system is running on low memory.

If you use `IntentService`, you don't need an `AsyncTask` anymore, it runs on the backround thread already. If you want to go with a regular `Service`, you will need to implement background execution on your own. Via java thread or async task for example.

Comment: Can you please state the benefits in using IntentService over AsyncTask and yes I have to update the UI when task is complete.

Comment: I've edited the answer. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi Gennadii, nice explanation. Can you please put some light on the following two points :-
1) What harm can calling AsyncTask from an Activity can cause.
2) If i use IntentService for the task, what are the good practices to populate data on UI thread ?

Comment: 1) If user closes the activity and your async task is still running then your activity object can't be recycled by GC and you will leak a lot of memory including the whole view hierarchy. 2) This is a separate topic.. In short, you should use a `Handler` attached to the UI thread, or, a `BroadcastReceiver`, whatever works better for you. In some cases if use a database, you can register a loader or `ContentObserver` which will be triggered once you write data to your db. The solution depends on your use case.

Comment: Thanks man !! I think i have enough information now to take it forward..

Answer (score 0):

If this is heavy and long running use a `Service` and communicate using **broadcast receivers**.

Comment: Can you please state the benefits in using Service over AsyncTask and yes I have to update the UI when task is complete.